# Dual boot Ubuntu gets stuck on shutdown. (New laptop)

Tags: ubuntu, multi-boot, shutdown, asus

I dual booted my new Asus Windows laptop with Ubuntu (latest). But it gets **stuck while shutting down only on UBUNTU**, I must press-hold the Power-Off key.

If I don't force shut-down, I get a screen stuck with an Asus and an Ubuntu watermark.

This is happening only on Ubuntu and the Windows side of things is working normally.

The device should just shut-down normally on my newly added Ubuntu, otherwise it's a problem. It's an Asus Vivobook 16X (16GB RAM, 512 GB SSD, i5-12450H Processor, Windows 11 pre-installed)

Comment: As usual, update UEFI should be the first troubleshooting step. The vast majority of the PCs in the market aren't designed for Linux and issues such as this and lack of hardware support often happens. This is typically solved (*when* it is solved) by an improved firmware. You may have to tweak some settings though. And when it's stuck try pressing ESC and see if there are error messages.

Comment: Also, when stuck, try this instead of forcefully shutting down: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key In a nutshell pres simultaneously ALT+SysRq and then in order R E I S U B